# Android Studio. Ask for help in videopath

Tags: java, android-studio

I already created raw folder but when I code R.raw the word raw its appear in red.
How should I do?

Eg:

[image]

Comment: Please insert part of code which contains error. Insert link to image is not good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Add some file in raw folder. Just rebuild your code. It will work.